# Thrift generated files with new compiler version name classes differently

Tags: thrift, generated-code

I updated my thrift compiler to the latest version, and it appears to be naming classes in the generated code differently than before. `T_User_UserBase` becomes `UserBase`. Of course, I have many references to the original class names in my code, and I'm wondering if there is a way to force thrift to generate class names with a custom prefix?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1330 this may be useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been a number of tickets all dealing with the various kinds of reserved words in all possible supported languages. Plus there have been other modifications, as the one you linked.

As a result, some things have been changed regarding the generated code in the past, even since 2012, and probably will change as it becomes necessary in the future.

That's not to say that compatiblity isn't an issue - it sure is. But in some cases potentially breaking changes are necessary, even if one tries to minimize them.